# unable to load Interop.Acrobat

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, acrobat

I have added the Acrobat com object in my application and use it successfully while debugging under visual studio.net 2010 framework 3.5, but whenever I deployed my application in IIS 7 and tried to browse the application, I got the error unable to load Interop.Acrobat

please help

Regards
Ahsan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential reason is x86/x64 mismatch - VS test host is 32 bit only, but IIS defaults to x64 on x64 OS.

Note: you are likely to run into troubles by using client application from server side code. There could be better options if you actually state what you want to achieve instead of what you want trying to do.

Comment: thanx for the response, I want to convert PDFs to HTML on the fly and I have seen a number of converters, and I have found this to be the best.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy the application, you will need to copy the automatically created Interop dll that was created in your bin directory.